# Easy way to create a form to email in SharePoint without using infopath

Tags: sharepoint

Does anyone know a good way to do this?  I need to have simple forms that submit to email without writing a lot of code.  These forms will be hosted in content-viewer web parts or similar in MOSS 2007.  I'd like to avoid using InfoPath.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a list which would give you the input form.

It depends on a) whether people should be able to see each other's submissions and b) who the e-mail should go to.

You could set an alert (Actions -> Alert Me) to send an e-mail to a person/people when a new item is added to the list.

In Settings -> List Settings -> Advanced Settings, there's the options for which items a user can see/edit.  Alerts however cannot be set on lists where  users can only see their own items.  In this case, I would use a simple workflow to send the e-mail.  I've only worked with MOSS 2007 and SharePoint Designer though - I'm not sure about WSS.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement a list as suggested above, and add an [SPItemEventReceiver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver_methods.aspx)  for sending emails when list items are added or changed (the link shows all of the events available to be handled)

Answer (score 0):

With the sharepoint sdk, you can create your own webparts. If you add them to the GAC you can include them on your sharepoint site. You'd of course have to build a webpart for emailing though.

Comment: I'd like to avoid creating a new webpart for this.  I want to be able to wire up webparts out of the box (with maybe a little HTML dropped in them).

Answer (score 0):

A workflow in Sharepoint Designer should be easiest way to implement it with no need to code.

Here's an article that explains how to do this:

**Workflow example: Send a notification message** : 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointdesigner/HA101829081033.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple HTML form in a text editor with the required `text boxes`, `text areas`, `select drop downs` etc, add a mailto tag and save.

Then add a page viewer web part under Media and content.

Select site actions, Edit page and under the editing tool tab select Format text, HTML Markup edit HTML source and paste your HTML form you created he text editor into the source window and select OK and save.